# Integrating factor mistake?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

Can someone help me get the Integrating factor for this?
$$y'\tan x+ y =e^{2x}\sin x$$

I got tan<sup>sec²X</sup>
But this was actually et multiple choice question and my teacher told me to retry the question as this was not amongst the options.

Comment: What's $\tan^{\sec^2X}$ and how did you get it?

Comment: You'll need to explain how you arrived at your answer, in order for us to determine where you made your mistake (as per your title question).

Answer (score 2):

$$y'\tan x + y =e^{2x}\sin x$$
Multiply by $\mu(x)= \cos x$
$$\implies y'\sin x + y \cos x =e^{2x}\sin x \cos x$$
$$\implies (y\sin x)' =\frac 12e^{2x}\sin(2x)$$

Integrate ...

Comment: Where's the integrating factor please?

Comment: it's already a derivative when you multiply by $ \mu (x)=\cos x$

Comment: I get what you did...but i don't want to solve the equation...I want to get the Integrating Factor

Comment: you are going to find $cos(x)$ as integrating factor

Answer (score 2):

Get your integral into the from

$y' + P(x) y = Q(x)$

and your integrating factor is $e^{\int P(x) \ dx}$

and then:

$e^{\int P(x) \ dx}y' + P(t)e^{\int P(x) \ dt} y = Q(x)e^{\int P(x) \ dx} \\
e^{\int P(x) \ dx} y =  Q(x)\int e^{\int P(x) \ dx} \ dx $

In this case.

$y' +  (\cot x) y = Q(x)\\
\int \cot x\ dx = \ln \sin x\\
e^{\ln\sin x} = \sin x$

But as Isham points out, it is not entirely necessary to divide through by $\tan x$ find in the integrating factor of $\sin x$ and multiply through by the integrating factor if you realise that $\int (\sin x) y' + (\cos x) y \ dx = (\sin x) y$

Comment: Thanks...guess integrating 1/tan x as ln(tanx)/sec²x wasn't a good Idea

Comment: You didn't do a valid substitution.  What it should look like is: $\frac {1}{\tan x} = \frac {\cos x}{\sin x}$ do the u-substitution $u = \sin x, du = \cos x \ dx$ leading to $\int \frac {1}{u} \ du$

Comment: +1 DougM is right the classical form of a first order equation is $y'+P(x)y=Q(x)$ Then the integrating factor is $\sin x$  .But if you keep the original form of the equation then the integrating factor is $\cos x$ ..

Answer (score 0):

Well, the integrating factor technique works as follows. We multiply the equation with $f(x)$ such that the left-hand side becomes $(f(x) y(x))'$. In this case, we multiply with $f/\tan$ to make our life easier. Then $f$ solves
$$ f'(x) = f(x)/\tan(x). $$
Bringing $f$ to the otherside and integrating we get
$$ \log(f(x)) = \int \frac{1}{\tan(x)}\,\mathrm{d} x = \log(\sin(x)). $$
Hence, the integrating factor will be
$$ \sin(x)/\tan(x) = \cos(x). $$

Answer (score 0):

$$y'+\cot(x)y=e^{2x}\cos(x)\\ \mu(x)=e^{\int \cot(x)dx}$$

$$\mu=e^{\ln\sin(x)} \\ \mu=\sin(x)$$

$$y\sin(x)=\frac12 \int e^{2x}\sin(2x)dx$$

$$y\sin(x)=\frac{1}{32} e^{2x}[\sin(2x)-4\cos(2x)]$$

$$\color{red}{y(x)= \frac{1}{32} e^{2x}[1-4\cot(2x)]}$$